# How to add class in v-if Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I want to higlight the text in color red if the status is Inactive. Below is my code

```
<td v-for="option in selected_type" v-if="option.id == item.status"  v-bind:class="add class here">
    @{{ option.status }}
</td>
```

Thank you

Comment: what is the name of the class?

Comment: I got it. Thanks :)

Comment: Please still mark an answer as correct!

Answer (score 4):

```
<td v-for="option in selected_type" :key="option.id" :class="{ inactive: item.status }">
```

I'm assuming the status property is a boolean
(Not sure why you're comparing the id with the status also)

```
.inactive { color: red; }
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple example, presuming that `status` is boolean:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    items: [
      { label: 'foo', status: true },
      { label: 'bar', status: false }
    ]
  }
})
```

```css
.text-red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p v-for="item in items" v-bind:class="{ 'text-red': item.status }">
    {{item.label}}
  </p>
</div>
```